# Prolog search list

Tags: prolog

In the code below, I am trying to search through a list and print "match" if there's a match in the list and print "no match" if there's no match. My code prints "match" if there's a match but, doesn't print "no match" instead returns false if there's no match. How can I change my code to print "no match" if there's no match in the list? thanks

```
    on(Item,[Item|_], X) :- X is 1.
    on(Item,[_|Tail],X):- on(Item,Tail,X).

    check(X,Y) :- on(X,Y,Z), (Z == 1, write('match');write('no match')).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a clause that catches the case when `on` reaches the end of the list:

```
on(_, [], X) :- X is 0.
```

However, in order to make that work, you need to put a cut operator, `!`, into the matching `on` clause, so that it doesn't continue and find the empty list matching clause also:

```
on(Item,[Item|_], X) :- X is 1, !.
```

Also, it looks like your printing code isn't doing what you want it to do, I think it should look something like:

```
(Z == 1 -> write('match'); write('no match')).
```

(note the `->` in there). I'm not positive that's correct, but I had to change it to make it work correctly on mine.

Finally, to make your code look a little bit prettier, you can put the `X is 0` and `X is 1` stuff into the predicate itself, so it becomes:

```
on(_, [], 0).
on(Item, [Item|_], 1) :- !.
```

Comment: thanks now its working. btw, what does the "->" operator do? mine is working with ','

Comment: @hmdb when I use the `,` I get it saying both `match` and `no match`. (if you're using swipl, are you pressing `;` or `.` after it prints `match`?) The `->` is the general if-then operator, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10122842/57318).

Comment: both `,` and `->` are working for me. I'm using swi-prolog and pressing `.` after it prints `match`

Comment: What if you press `;` after it?

Comment: you're correct it prints both `match` and `no match` if I press `;`