# If statement on Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and I am just wondering how do you write an `if` statement in it.

I am trying to get a 10x10 grid with walls on the outside, in the middle I am moving an object but I am having trouble trying to work out how I stop the robot from going outside of the grid i.e. if the robot hits the wall stop and tell user that they have can't move any further because you can't go through a wall.

Here is the code so far.

```
choose(left):-
      square(R,C,robot),
      NR is R + 1,
      retract(square(R,C,robot)),
      assert(square(NR,C,robot)),
      NR > 9, fail,
      status.
```

Comment: The answer to your previous question if full of `if`s

Comment: See [if else if else clause in prolog similar to C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122780/if-else-if-else-clause-in-prolog-similar-to-c-c)

Comment: Why not just use `NR < 10` instead?